# Why am I getting "implementation of Deref is not general enough"?

Tags: rust, rust-diesel, rust-axum

Here's my minimum reproducible example:

```rust
use axum::{extract::State, Json, Router};
use diesel::pg::Pg;
use diesel_async::{
    pooled_connection::bb8::Pool,
    AsyncConnection, AsyncPgConnection, RunQueryDsl,
};

fn main() {
    // body omitted for brevity
}

pub type AsyncPool = Pool<AsyncPgConnection>;

fn router() -> Router<AsyncPool> {
    use axum::routing::*;
    Router::new().route("/create", post(create))
}

async fn create(State(db): State<AsyncPool>) -> Result<Json<()>, ()> {
    let mut conn = db.get().await.unwrap();
    let user = create_user(&mut conn).await?;

    Ok(Json(user))
}

// actual return types omitted for brevity
async fn create_user(conn: &mut impl AsyncConnection<Backend = Pg>) -> Result<(), ()> {
    // error doesn't happen without this line, which is even more confusing
    diesel::dsl::sql_query("real query omitted for brevity")
        .execute(conn)
        .await
        .unwrap();
    Ok(())
}
```

Trying to compile this on Rust 1.70 gives the following error:

```
error: implementation of `Deref` is not general enough
  --> src/main.rs:27:36
   |
27 |     Router::new().route("/create", post(create))
   |                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^ implementation of `Deref` is not general enough
   |
   = note: `Deref` would have to be implemented for the type `bb8::api::PooledConnection<'0, AsyncDieselConnectionManager<AsyncPgConnection>>`, for any lifetime `'0`...
   = note: ...but `Deref` is actually implemented for the type `bb8::api::PooledConnection<'1, AsyncDieselConnectionManager<AsyncPgConnection>>`, for some specific lifetime `'1`
```

I already don't understand why this error is happening, because the implementations of `Deref` and `DerefMut` for `bb8::PooledConnection` look general enough to me:

```rust
impl<'a, M> Deref for PooledConnection<'a, M>
where
    M: ManageConnection,
{
    type Target = M::Connection;

    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        &self.conn.as_ref().unwrap().conn
    }
}

impl<'a, M> DerefMut for PooledConnection<'a, M>
where
    M: ManageConnection,
{
    fn deref_mut(&mut self) -> &mut M::Connection {
        &mut self.conn.as_mut().unwrap().conn
    }
}
```

But what's even more confusing is that the error goes away if I don't call `diesel_async::run_query_dsl::RunQueryDsl::execute()` on the connection object inside of `create_user`, OR if I call `.deref_mut()` manually:

```rust
// calling deref_mut manually makes the error go away. why?
let user = create_user(conn.deref_mut()).await?;
```

Why is this compile error happening, and why does it go away under these circumstances? How is it possible that calling `execute()` is able to implicitly place additional lifetime constraints on the parameter `conn`?

Comment: This looks like a bug of the compiler to me, maybe you should try opening an issue.

Comment: Yes the error message indicates that this is another instance of a long known compiler bug related to async code and lifetimes. It should be possible to workaround that by just not using a generic `&mut impl AsyncConnection` type as function parameter, but rather the specific `&mut AsyncPgConnection` type.

Comment: @weiznich If this bug is already known, would you be able to point me to the GitHub issue that tracks it? I don't really know what to type into Google.

Comment: I think https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/101794 might be one of the issues that track this kind of restrictions.